# Simple way to loop through array of objects and compare results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, foreach

I have an array of 15 objects each containing a single key-value pair. How can I go about looping through this array to check if the key value pair in each object has a certain value, e.g "Yes"? Keeping in mind that I am already looping through 25 objects, and each of these  objects has this array in it.

Here is my code:

```
    let results = Object.keys(halls);
    let filtered = [];
    results.filter(key => {
        if (postcode == halls[key]['Location'][3]['Postcode'] && suburb == "") {return true;};

        arrayC.map((x) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                if (halls[key]['Facility'][i][`${x}`] == "Yes") {return true;}
            };
        }); 
        return false;
    }).forEach(key => filtered.push([halls[key]]));
```

I think the issue might be with how I am returning true in the for loop, but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated! (And no I can't change the data structure)

**UPDATE**

Working Code:

```
        for (let a = 0; a < 15; a++) {
            let x = arrayC[a];
            for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                if (halls[key]['Facility'][i][`${x}`] == "Yes") {return true;}
            };
        };
```

Comment: Your instinct appears correct: returning `true` inside the `map` callback will not return at the `filter` level. If you want to do that, consider a `for` loop

Comment: You could use `.every()` instead of the inner `.map`, although you would have to return false and then have another return based off the value from every. What Nick suggested works, where you can have for loops you name to break out of. You can also set an outer boolean condition to break out as necessary to return properly.

Answer (score 1):

First extract the 15 items logic into separate function. Instead of using `map`, we use `every`, as you are interested in finding; does each one of the item's value is "Yes". (If you want to find only some of the item has value "yes" switch `every` with `some`)

```
EveryItemsValueIsYes(array, key){
    const elements = array.every(item => {
        for(let i=0; i<15; i++){
            if(halls[key]['Facility'][i][`${x}`] == "Yes"){
                return true;
            }
        }   
    });
    return elements.length > 0;
}
```

Replace the internal array map code with the function.

Also instead of using `forEach` at the end, we can replace it with `map` and directly assign values to filtered.

```
const filtered = results.filter((key) => {
if (postcode == halls[key]['Location'][3]['Postcode'] && suburb == "") {return true;}
    return EveryItemsValueIsYes(arrayC, key);
}).map(key => halls[key]);
```

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work - Instead I had a for loop instead of the map (see question) but thanks for the info around .every